# How to decode function name of smart contract in Polygon network?

Tags: solidity, web3js, matic

I have deployed contract(not mine), abi is not provided.

Input data used in transaction:

```
0xd1700e6c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Could someone help, how to call this function directly from web3? Or how to find out it's name. As I understand, when you call contract function you write: `contract.methods.func().send()`. But how to call/send function if I only have methodId?

txid: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x165f8d6e2b5a75a4daad8950444e2c31bba027da0b8c1b21ac760a954e69af88

Comment: You can only call a smart contract's function if you have both its address and its abi.

Comment: @NuMa i know some ppl call it directly without abi somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a raw transaction containing the function selector (as well as the function arguments) in the `data` field, sign it, and send it to your node provider to broadcast it to the network.

```
// the sender private key needs to be added to web3 `accounts.wallet`
// see the blue "note" card in the docs for more details

await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: senderAddress,
    to: contractAddress,
    data: "0xd1700e6c..."
});
```

Docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction